# UITableView duplicate row's

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is the code im using in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"OBBirthControlMethodsTableCell";
    OBCustomDetailCell *cell = (OBCustomDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"cell id - %@",cell.subviews);
    CGRect frame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:0];
    if(nil == cell)
    {
        cell = [[[OBCustomDetailCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.row != 3)
        {
            //Setting the basic template
            UIView *template = [[UIView alloc] init];
            template.tag = indexPath.row+10;
            NSLog(@"path index = %d",indexPath.row);
            UIImageView *templateImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                                                       200,
                                                                                       frame.size.height)];
            UILabel *templateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(templateImage.frame.size.width+20,
                                                                               0,
                                                                               cell.frame.size.width - templateImage.frame.size.width+20,
                                                                               frame.size.height)];
            [template addSubview:templateImage];
            [template addSubview:templateLabel];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:template];
        }
    }

    UIView *templateView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 10];
    if (templateView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Gotten a templateView object");
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            templateView.frame = frame;

            for (UIView *view in templateView.subviews)
            {
                if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                {
                    [(UIImageView *)view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"baby.jpeg"]];
                }
                else if  ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                {
                    [(UILabel *)view setText:@"This is not working"];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            templateView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50,
                                            frame.size.width,
                                            frame.size.height);

        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But the issue is that the new cell is giving me the same values os the old cell the new cell that is dequeued once you scroll down ..

**EDIT**
A duplicate cell is being created as soon as we scroll down to a new cell with the same vales of the 1st cell ..

- I would like the UIView to be created for only select rows() ..if (indexPath.row != 3)
- and i would like the location of the UIView to be different in some of the rows .. if (indexPath.row == 0)

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the text not being updated? Is the separate cell at `indexPath.row == 3` not working? What is it?

Comment: i have added a clearer explanation of the issue

Comment: **where and when do you remove the unwanted** `template` **view from the cells?** because the dequeued cells have this view and it seems you add two or more times the new instance of the template `UIView` for the same cell without removing the exists one from them. you are just wasting the memory and you make yourself headache. why don't you work different custom cells with different `cellID` for the different kind of cells? this solution is very rough...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with this bit of code. First and foremost, the primary cause of your issues is this bit:

```
template.tag = indexPath.row+10;
```

Why are you doing this? Just use a constant value, like `10`. No need to involve the index path, since that will change for each cell. This will cause `viewWithTag:` to fail for reused cells, and it will return `nil`.

Second, you can't only set up your template cell for `indexPath.row != 3`, because at some point, the non-template cell may be reused. It will not have the template views, so the following layout will fail. You'll need to use two reuse identifiers for the two types of cells. The final product should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *templateCellIdentifier = @"OBBirthControlMethodsTableCell";
    static NSString *otherCellIdentifier = @"OtherTableCell";

    if (indexPath.row != 3) {
        // Handle normal cells
        OBCustomDetailCell *cell = (OBCustomDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:templateCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[OBCustomDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:templateCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            // Set up template cell
        }
        // Handle per-cell data
    } else {
        // Handle special cells
        OBCustomDetailCell *cell = (OBCustomDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:otherCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[OBCustomDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:otherCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            // Set up other cell
        }
        // Handle per-cell data (not really necessary if there's only one of these)
    }
}
```